# Since $E[E[X\vert \mathcal{A}]1_{A}]=E[X1_{A}]$ does $E[E[X\vert \mathcal{A}]]=E[X]$ always hold?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

I have shown for a measurable $A$ that $E[E[X\vert \mathcal{A}]1_{A}]=E[X1_{A}]$

Does this mean $E[E[X\vert \mathcal{A}]]=E[X]$ always holds?

since $E[E[X\vert \mathcal{A}]]=E[E[X\vert \mathcal{A}]1_{\Omega}]=E[X1_{\Omega}]=E[X]$, where $\Omega$ is the actual outcome space.

In other words, if the expectation of conditional expectation always expectation itself?

Comment: Yes. That is part of the definition of the conditional expectation as you pointed out.

Comment: By construction, the conditional expectation is the unique random variable that satisfies this (law of total expectation) (adding measurability)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a true statement, and as you note it is an immediate consequence of the definition of conditional expectation.